# Add a unique id to an element located inside multiple child elements in XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, unique

I am trying to create an XML Schema to have a unique id for an element that is located inside several child elements in XML. An element in this case is "actor" and it is located inside "actors" which in turn is located inside "cast" element.

I want each movie ID to be unique, and each actor ID to be unique within that movie ID. I'm not sure where I need to put "unique" for the "actor" element that is located inside "actors" and "cast" child elements.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<movie_database
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">

<movie movieID="1">
    <title>Movie 1</title>
    <cast>
        <directors>Bob</directors>
        <writers>Tom</writers>      
        <actors>
            <actor actorID="1"> 
                <name>Jack</name>
            </actor>
            <actor actorID="2">
                <name>James</name>
            </actor>
        </actors>   
    </cast>
</movie>
</movie_database>
```

XML Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:element name="movie_database">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="movie" type="movietype" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:unique name="unique_actorid">
                    <xs:selector xpath="actor"/>
                    <xs:field xpath="@actorID"/>
                </xs:unique>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="unique_movieid">
        <xs:selector xpath="movie"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@movieID"/>
    </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="movietype">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="cast" type="casttype"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="movieID" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="casttype">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="directors" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="writers" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="actors" type="actorsAll"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="actorsAll">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="actor" type="actorType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="actorType" mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="actorID" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule is that the `<xs:unique>` goes on the topmost element that gives the scope within which you need uniqueness, the selector gives the path from this point down to the elements that should be unique, and the field(s) are relative to the selected element.

So for unique actors within a movie you have a few choices. Since each `movie` has exactly one `cast` which in turn has exactly one `actors` you could put the constraint on the actors element with a selector of `actor`, on cast with a selector of `actors/actor` or on the movie with a selector of `cast/actors/actor`. In all cases the field xpath would be `@actorID` as this is relative to the selected `actor` elements.

As an aside, the schema you've given would only allow a movie to have one actor, I guess you've forgotten the `maxOccurs="unbounded"` on the `actor` element inside `actorsAll`.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I have actually tried to put the constraint on the movie with a selector of cast/actors/actor, but because I have forgotten the maxOccurs="unbounded" I kept on getting "this element is not expected" error so I could never know if that constraint worked. Now it all makes sense. Thank you so much!